# MacBook Pro 15" Retina Display

Tags: macos, mac, macbook, macbook-pro, macbook-pro-retina

I purchased my MBP in December 2012, and now that I have to use it for work, I'm seeing ghost imaging when I swipe between screens. I completely feel like this shouldn't happen because it's basically brand new. The longevity that I perceive of any Apple product should be more than about a year and a half... I love my Mac to pieces and it is by far the best computer I've ever used.

Any suggestions as to why the ghosting appears or what I can do to ease the pain?

Answer (score 2):

Apple is [aware of this](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5455) and states "This is normal behavior for an IPS display, and the faint image will disappear over time."

Unfortunately, it seems that nothing can be done to solves this. Possibly take it to an Apple store and describe the issue - see if they can give any recommendations.